# c++ returning const reference of local variable

Tags: c++, reference, constants, inline

is it possible/ok to return a const reference even if the value the function returns is a local variable of this function? i know that locals are not valid anymore once the function returns - but what if the function is inlined and the returned value is only used within the callers scope? then the locals of the function should be included in the callers stackframe, no?

Comment: Is the local variable itself a `const` or just the returned reference to it?

Answer (score 8):

Don't count on it. Even if this works on 1 compiler, it's not standard supported behavior and is likely to break on others.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not OK. Local variables are declared on the stack, and the stack keeps changing between method calls. Also, the objects that get out of scope get destroyed. Always return a copy of a local variable.

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass() { cout << "ctor" << endl; }
  ~MyClass() { cout << "dtor" << endl; }
  MyClass(const MyClass& r) { cout << "copy" << endl; }
};

const MyClass& Test()
{
  MyClass m;
  return m;
}

int main()
{
  cout << "before Test" << endl;
  MyClass m = Test();
  cout << "after Test" << endl;
}
```

This will print out:

```
before Test
ctor
dtor
copy
after Test
dtor
```

The object you're trying to copy has already called its destructor and may be in an invalid state.

Answer (score 4):

`inline` is **not** a guarantee -- it's a **suggestion**. Even if you use tricks to force inline, you'll never be sure about the result, especially if you want to remain portable.

Hence, **don't** do it.

Answer (score 1):

Doing that invokes undefined behaviour.

- There's no way of forcing a compiler to inline the function. `inline` is just a suggestion - so is `__forceinline`
- Even if you could guarantee that the function would be inlined, the destructor for the variable in question will still be executed, leaving you with a reference to a dead object.
- And the big one - **C++'s concept of the stack is delimited by scope - not by function.**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  {
    int a = 5;
    std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << &a << std::endl;
  }
  {
    int b = 10;
    std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << &b << std::endl;
  }
}
```

My compiler puts 'a' and 'b' at different memory address. *Except when I turn optimizations on.* Yours may well decide that it's an optimization to reuse the memory your object previously occupied.

Is there a paticular problem you're trying to solve here? There are other ways of reducing the number of temporary objects created if that's your concern.

Comment: Do you remember where exactly did you learn that C++ stack is delimited by scope?

Comment: No. But destructor calls happen at the scope boundary, not the function boundary, so it seems obvious.

Comment: Not really. Destructors get called on the scope boundary, but that doesn't mean that the stack gets winded or unwinded on that boundary. I just had a look in disassebly of a simple app that has 2 scopes nested in another, and saw that nothing happens to the stack pointer. Tried both release and debug builds. Well, I guess the correct answer would be - it's compiler-specific.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, this is dangerous.  It's also unnecessary, if your compiler supports the NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization), and your function uses and returns the local variable you would have liked to return by ref in a fairly simple way.

The NRVO allows the compiler to avoid copy construction under certain conditions - typically the main reason to avoid returning objects by value.  VC++ 8 supports this (a delta on previous revisions) and it makes quite a bit of perf diff in frequently used code.

Answer (score 0):

The value falls out of scope when the callee falls out of scope. So no, it is gone.

But if you want a fairly ugly solution (and a red flag warning you that your design might need refactoring), you can do something like this:

```
const MyObj& GetObj()
{
  static const MyObj obj_;
  return obj_;
}
```

...but this solution if fraught with peril, especially if the object is modifyable, or does something non-trivial in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: For unmodifiable objects, this is actually not a bad solution.

Comment: If they're immutable, they can be declared in the outer scope and there's no need to actually return them.

Answer (score 0):

The inline keyword doesn't guarantee that the function is really inlined. Don't do it.